# Newsletter2Go endpoint /forms/submit{{form_id}}

Tags: newsletter2go

I created a wrapper for using the newsletter2go endpoint

- [https://api.newsletter2go.com/forms/submit/{{form_id}}](https://api.newsletter2go.com/forms/submit/%7B%7Bform_id%7D%7D)

When I post the request to that ep w/ an form_id I get the following response:

- http status: 400
- code: 10020
- error message: Bad Request (invalid code xxxx)

Im using the id from the n2go backend:

[image: id from n2go be]

Can anyone tell me whats about the error code 10020? The api docs containing nothing about that.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I've ran into the same issue today. And it's all lowercase..

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you used big letters in your form_id. I had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177739/newsletter2go-api-bad-request). The support told me, that only small letters are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I found finally out what the `form_id` have to be. It's the value you see in the Opt-In Email for the `n2g` argument, for example:

```
https://subscribe.newsletter2go.com?n2g=dummy-code-here
```

Otherweise check the sourcecode of the Embedded Form, there is a script in it which contains the form id.

Maybe this helps someone one day.